# Add help for Markdown spoiler tags in the formatting help

Tags: support, spoilers, markdown, help-center

Is it possible to get some more "help" added to the [Formatting help page](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/editing-help) particularly for Spoiler markdown?

For example, it would be useful to be able to see how to put new lines and empty lines in a Spoiler Block. The simple return character does not behave as might be expected.

Example:

> Spoiler Line One.
>  Spoiler Line Two.

Comment: I fixed the markdown. Note: Your question is rather unclear.

Comment: I'm not sure how to make it clearer, maybe by removing my failed attempts...

Comment: I would suggest by clarifying what your _actual_ question is.

Comment: Use the <br> break character instead of a carriage return. Simples

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### According to [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99895/editing-comment-help-page#comment253875_99895) from eons ago, no one here can. However you can ask it on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) and they *may* help.

As far as I can research, the mods (and certainly the users) are unable to change the formatting page specifically for SFF. It is set by the developers, although changes have been implemented from Meta.SE they won't add every example in.

---

As for your specific problem, what you need to do is to add **two spaces** at the end of the line to force a line break, for example

```
>! Para 1  
>!  
>! Para 2
```

(With two spaces after the top two lines) renders as:

> Para 1
>
>  Para 2

Whereas without the two spaces, one gets:

> Para 1
>
>  Para 2

And with only two spaces on the middle line, one gets:

> Para 1
>
>  Para 2

Comment: It's good to know the how, even if the edit page is out of scope.

Comment: `As far as I can research the mods` I'd love to know how you _researched_ the mods.

Comment: @Möoz \* *checks for hidden cameras* \*

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way to put blank lines and breaks into spoiler text (or any blockquote text) is to use the 'break' command

[image]

```
>! My text goes here. <br> This text goes on the next line. <br> <br> <br> I can also use multiple breaks to create multiple line breaks.
```

> My text goes here. 
>  This text goes on the next line. 
>  
>  
>  I can also use multiple breaks to create multiple line breaks.

Comment: It looks like you can only have one right answer,  so I should probably leave it where it is. But thanks for the other solution. I should really have thought of that myself.

Comment: Ugh, <br> as a substitute for <p> is really ugly.  But Chrome tells me the other answer *also* produces ugly <br> tags, so meh.

Comment: @Kevin There's no "pretty" way to do it. I, too, use break tags for spoilers

Comment: @Machavity spaces are pretty, they're invisible ;)

Answer (score 0):

As a side note, among other things that probably need to be documented, if not fixed, it's not possible currently to put spoiler and non-spoiler quotes next to each other. I currently handle it by putting some non-quoted text (Laurel suggests using an unsupported HTML tag like "<!>") in between like the following:

> This is a quote that I'm including.

> This is the spoiler part that I didn't want immediately visible.

Comment: There's a way to do it without having random text in between: just add (e.g.) `<!>`, which the system interprets as an unsupported HTML tag and strips it out.